# Print screen key is not working in VMware ESXi

Tags: vmware, esxi, printscreen

I am configuring a virtual machine on VMware EXCi 7, using the web interface for accessing to the screen of the VM.

I need to use the Print Screen key for the OS configuration, but is not working.
I´m using my laptop keyboard (IS NOT A PROBLEM WITH THE FN KEY), and right now I do not another keyboard to try with it.
There is something necessary to use this key on VMware ESXi?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue installing VMRC on my computer, and launching this remote console.